# Excel: Can you use IFS for multiple criteria on median

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ifs

Excel does not have a function to sort for multiple criteria for MEDIAN() as it does with AVERAGEIFS() or SUMIFS().

I have been sorting multiple criteria for median with nested IF() statements. For example, suppose I have a rent roll and I'm looking to calculate the median rent of a particular unit type that's occupied, I would do:

> > =MEDIAN(IF(unitType="1x1",IF(leaseStatus="Occd",rent)))

Where unitType, leaseStatus, and rent are arrays of data.

Is it possible to rewrite this function using IFS()? I have not been successful. I tried for example:

> > MEDIAN(IFS(unitType="1x1",leaseStatus="Occd",rent))

with no success.

Thanks in advance.

This post does not discuss how:
[Optimizing multiple-criteria IFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059173/optimizing-multiple-criteria-ifs)

Comment: Do you have some sample data with expected output. Doesn't have to be much but It's easier to work with than none.

Comment: I think you're confusing `IFS` with functions such as `AVERAGEIFS`, `SUMIFS`. You're correct that there is no function `MEDIANIFS`, and to rewrite your current formula so as to use `IFS` (`=MEDIAN(IFNA(IFS((unitType="1x1")*(leaseStatus="Occd"),rent),""))`) would be both convoluted and an inappopriate use of that function.

Comment: Thank you @JosWoolley. So what is the best way to implement the multiple criteria? The way I showed with nested IF()?

Comment: Yes, your current formula is optimal.

Comment: @JosWoolley Thank you.

Comment: @user1527227 - I have a different view RE: JW's comment concerning 'optimality' - whilst this is a vague term in its own right, I argue there is an even more 'efficient' method to calculate; provide 4 variants (including your 'double-if'); and weight up relative pros/cons in this regard.  Kindly consider and vote up/down accordingly for the benefit of future users.  Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9-hYyz2oeO_KAckGv?e=xNpCrL) /screenshot(s) refer.

RE your Q:

> "*Is it possible to rewrite this function using IFS()?* "

**(1) (v.) SHORT ANS..**

**YES**
(if one ***must***... cf. cell G8):

```
=MEDIAN(IFS((Table1[Letter]="A")*(Table1[Colour]="blue"),Table1[value],1,""))
```

[image: M4: attaining result using (unnecessarily) 'IFs' statement]

---

**High level conclusions**
*See below for further info RE: M1-4 (corres. Method 1-4 resp.)*

**M1**. `Nested if` (M1, given) is natural starting pt. yet *rendered unnecessary* by latest software version (i.e. Office 365 compatible Excel); *thus room for improvement/refinement remains*

**M2**. Prosaic '`single-if`' method appears to be an *improvement over* M1 given elimination of *nested `if` method* (however, this depends upon one's defn. of optimality to begin with).

**M3**. Parsimonious: `filter` - per below: recommended method provided  Office 365 Excel version is avail. (failing which, M2)

**M4**. `Ifs` (M4) possible yet *inappropriate/superfluous* given nature of
filter in Q

**---------------------------------------------------------------------**

**(2) VARIANTS & REL. MERITS**

IFs statement akin to If/else if/else if etc. compound statement; you're looking for a compound If statement as opposed to a series of sequential filters that suffer from the unnecessary ordered dependency for the filtration in question.

Here is a comparison table highlighting relative merits/otherwise for 4 different methods/calc. bases (incl. the variant given in the body of the Q [M1] and the IFs variant / equivalent [M4]:

*functions corres. to respective cells/comparison table (G5-G7):*

***M1: cell G5***
[image: M1: Double if - given]

*(see Q for gen. basis of formula/compound-nested If function)*

***M2: cell G6***

[image: M2: Prosaic 'single-if' method]

***M3: cell G7***

[image: M3: Parsimonious 'filter' method]

***M4: cell G8***

- Relies upon *double ifs* per Q.
- *fn: see v. first function 'v. short A' above*

**---------------------------------------------------------------------**

**(3) COMPARISON OF M1-4**

*See table in first screenshot provided above*

Comment: Thank you so much.  Which method would you use?

Comment: If I had office 365 (which I do) - I tend to prefer something like M3 - BUT, as not a lot of people are exceptionally familiar with this method, should my work be subject to review by others/colleagues etc., it might be better to stick with something like M1/M2.  When working on my own projects/personal workbooks etc., I'd try to maintain consistency so that if there is an error with one of the functions/formulae, it's a little easier to trace collateral 'damage' so to speak... :)